# Defining a class method and an instance method with the same name

Tags: python

In python, is it possible to define an instance method and a class method with the same name?

Example:

```
class C:
    def f (self):
        print("Inst")

    @classmethod
    def f (cls):
        print("Cls")

c = C()
c.f() #This should print "Inst"
C.f() #This should print "Cls"
```

In the example code, the `classmethod` definition seems to overwrite the first one.

Comment: No, the execution of the class definition will be top to bottom, so `c.f` and `C.f` will always be the classmethod in this case, since it will be overwritten

Comment: What would you say will be the final result of `a` after doing: `a = 1 ; a = 2`? This is basically the same thing

Comment: @Tomerikoo. And yet, you have two separate namespaces, so there is no really good reason not to.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not sure I understand. no good reason not to what?

Comment: @Tomerikoo. No good reason you couldn't do it given that there are two separate namespaces involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it the way you propose, but it is possible. Let's look at how namespaces and decorators work to understand how and why.

The syntax `@classmethod` is shorthand for calling the decorator function `classmethod` and storing the result under the same name as the object being decorated. It is syntactic sugar for the following:

```
def f (cls):
    print("Cls")

f = classmethod(f)
```

Namespaces, including the class namespace, are basically dictionaries. That means you can have exactly one object assigned to a given name. You can re-assign the name as many times as you want, which is what your code is doing:

1. Assign function `f` as instance method.
2. Create another function and assign it to `f`.
3. Decorate `f`, and assign it back to the same name as shown above.

All three operations overwrite the result of the previous.

However, the class and the instance have separate namespaces. There is nothing stopping you from having a different object assigned to `f` in each one, but you have to do it carefully.

For example:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        def f():
            print("Inst")
        self.f = f

    @classmethod
    def f (cls):
        print("Cls")

c = C()
c.f() # Prints "Inst"
C.f() # Prints "Cls"
```

What this does is to assign to the name `f` in the namespace of the class as well as the instance, separately. Since functions are non-data descriptors (they have a `__get__` method to bind, but don't have a `__set__` method), calling `c.f()` will access the `f` in `c` rather than looking into the class first.

Compare to properties, which are data descriptors. Even if you have an attribute `f` in the instance, accessing it when there is a `property` named `f` in the class would be impossible using simple dot notation.

The instance "method" will not be a bound method object as such. It will be a normal function, but with access to `self` through its enclosing nonlocal namespace. This is probably going to be sufficient for most applications. However, if you really needed a bound method, you could accomplish that as well, by wrapping a method with a different name and assigning it to the instance:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.f = self._f # This creates a bound method

    def _f(self):
        print("Inst")

    @classmethod
    def f (cls):
        print("Cls")

c = C()
c.f() # Prints "Inst"
C.f() # Prints "Cls"
```